# Session cannot be started, File name too long (36)

Tags: php, apache

I have a php application (Apache , Php-fpm )on a RedHat server and I have the error when calling sesssion_start():

```
session_start(): open(/tmp/sess_CGr5ZiSQDdHxDm685fm5VX7,bPAfwVW841U9OKDZxObglASxB1uQFE,3csTnWpecsq7Nxvdw9NkZLvhEWs3lrLAWtLHWbMfcmK,G2vg9,i2cyHu6m1o,WsjMfKvcmkrYRQmbWqf,cz0O31IJdPSkwbXcsYldjiptc6UTTShW8TQb7-k2slvtt7GKEz5MVLofDg8TqP4bbBP7q24Wx,4Nh52sgpUfYwkycD3OJycyPbQFcKRfLR0yXVTToBfVKHlI, O_RDWR) failed: File name too long (36)
```

I have tried to change the session.save_path to /tmp, given the proper permissions, but no luck.
Has someone faced this issue? Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: the error says (File name too long)

Comment: Yes @mmh4all, but how can I change the size of the filename is my problem..thanks

Comment: check this link https://serverfault.com/questions/388858/how-to-fix-file-name-too-long-error-in-apache2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding this value to my php-fpm pool config (www.conf) solved the issue, thanks @mmh4all for helping

```
php_value['session.sid_length'] = xx
```

xx can be between 22 and 256. I used 30 in my case.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. `xx`  does not look like a legit value to me, as that should be a number

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).